# How to have vlookup return multiple columns in one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am putting together a list of items bought by buyer and am trying to get it to list out in one cell. I have tried to do this using vlookup and textjoin but can not get it to display information. I want to take a customer name from one sheet then display all the SKUs bought in one cell.

```
=TEXTJOIN("",1,VLOOKUP(A12,Display_sales_named,{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},0))

= VLOOKUP(A3,Display_sales_named,TEXTJOIN("",1,{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}),0)
```

The image is the table I am pulling from and I am trying to display the information in a table on another sheet.

[image]

Comment: Your first formula works just fine if you confirm it with <CTRL><SHIFT><ENTER>. I recommend you use `", "` or something like it as a delimiter

Comment: +1 for providing your existing (input) data.  −¼ for sizing the columns so we can’t see the data, −¼ for not saying what `Display_sales_named` is, −¼ for not explaining why you have multiple columns for each year (and not even an obvious, regular pattern), and −¼ for not showing what result data what you want.  So, no upvote for you. But fix those problems and you might get the +1.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this non-array formula :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,INDEX($C$2:$P$100,MATCH(A12,$A$2:$A$100,0),0))
```